# Retrieve the controller name from a class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to retrieve a controller name given a class name. That is, I have

```
Articles::Category
```

and I would like to retrieve

```
articles/categories
```

I would like to retrieve the controller name inside a view file not related to the `Articles::Categories` controller.

How can I do that (possibly using some Ruby on Rails core method)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Articles::Category.name.underscore.pluralize
=> "articles/categories"
```

As mentioned by many others, there is no special method for that. But as long as you followed Rails conventions, this approach will take you far.

Answer (score 4):

To get the controller name, say inside your view, you can do :

```
<%= controller.controller_name %>
```

To get the name of a class, say User, if you have a user object named user :

```
user.class.to_s
```

Other than that, i don't think there's a correlation between a controller and a model, that can give you the controller name from a class name, because they are different things. You can maybe create a hash like {:controller => 'class_name'} and map those yourself.

Comment: I fear it doesn't answer the question

Comment: But, i answer in the last paragraph apneadiving :) I say that, to my knowledge, you cannot do that.

Comment: Backo, in your update, you say that you would like to receive the controller name inside a view file. You can do that with the first code snippet in my answer.

Comment: @SpyrosP - Calling '<%= controller.controller_name %>' method inside a view file not related to the 'Articles::Categories' controller I will get the controller name of the current controller (that is, not the 'Articles::Categories' controller).

Comment: But views are tied to controllers. If you have, say, a user controller with a user view, you do not invoke that view from another controller, unless it's a partial, in which case, you would still get the current controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
Articles::Categories.name.underscore #=> articles/categories
```

And it underscores camelcased words to so that:

```
RailsAdmin::ApplicationHelper.name.underscore #=> rails_admin/application_helper
```

Comment: As long as you haven't deviated from the naming conventions Rails relies on, this seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: @gunn @jaydel - I was wrong. I was referring to 'Articles::Category' class name and not to 'Articles::Categories' class name! I updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really meant `Articles::CategoriesController` then `Articles::CategoriesController.controller_path` will give you what you want.

**Update** The question is, given the name of a Rails Model, how do you get the name of the associated controller?

The answer to that question is, you can't. There is not a one-to-one mapping from the model name to the controller name. The `User` model could be controlled by the `users_controller.rb` and/or `admin/users_controller.rb` or not have an associated controller at all. You can certainly guess at some likely possibilities based on Rails conventions but you can't know.

Comment: @ - I get this error: NoMethodError 'undefined method `controller_path' for #<Class:0x00000106a3cf08>'.

Comment: There must be some mistake, `controller_path` is defined on all classes that inherit from `ActionController::Base`. Are you trying to get the controller_path for the controller associated with a model, i.e. something that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: I have the *model* **name** (Articles::Category) and I would like to retrieve the related *controller* "**name**" (articles/categories).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `underscore.pluralize` just use [`tableize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-tableize):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.name.tableize
=> "active_record/bases"
```